# How to Completely disable keyboard when using EditText in android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keyboard

I have 5 EditTexts and I type in them using 5 buttons, so I don't need the keyboard.

How can I disable it completely, even when I click on the `EditText`? On `EditText` click I want only to focus it so that it has the cursor on. (I implemented everything so that when I click one of the 5 buttons, the focus goes on the next `EditText`).

The problem is that when I click on an `EditText` the keyboard pops up. I think I have to do it in java. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
MyEditor.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int inType = MyEditor.getInputType(); // backup the input type
        MyEditor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // disable soft input
        MyEditor.onTouchEvent(event); // call native handler
        MyEditor.setInputType(inType); // restore input type
        return true; // consume touch event
    }
});
```

Comment: Always try to add some description when adding snippets.

Comment: this disables the cursor too....How to disable keyboard but cursor should remain when edittext is pressed ?

Answer (score 1):

Try  :

```
editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
editText.setFocusable(false);
```